# Browser viewport is different between browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

So I have noticed that a website I created looks bigger in Chrome than it does in IE11.

I couldn't figure out why. The zoom was set to 100% in both browsers.

If I go to http://viewportsizes.com/mine/ it reports the following viewport sizes:

Chrome - 1280 × 619 and IE11 - 1920 × 906

My question is why does this happen? How can the two browsers report back two largely different sizes?

Comment: Please share the link

Answer (score 1):

Please tell me what device are you using? (IE Version, Windows Version, Device size)

Probably you use a mobile device (like 10 inch tablet) with Full HD resolution. Unfortunately I have no such Windows device, but this is a common behavior of mobile devices and chrome/firefox.

The reason shortly is that *viewport* does not represent the screen resolution and is mostly optimized for better user experience. Here I mean, that for an 10 inch device, browsing webpages in full resolution would result in a non readable webpage, a short example you can find here
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml

More details about *viewport* you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Note that IE is 'integrated' with the operating system, meaning, that DPI settings on your device also should have influence on IE (icon text size on your desktop and context menu text size is probably the same as a text in IE).